# Create and structure a complex seating structure in SQL?

Tags: java, mysql, data-structures

I am trying to create a data structure for stadium seating in mySQL for a booking system. I want to be able to query the database, to iterate over blocks to create a graphic representation and be able to book seats. The situation is:

- Many blocks of seats, we'll say A to G.
- 'x' amounts of rows of seats A,B,C… varying by block.
- 'y' numbers of seats, varying by row (A: 35,B:32 etc)
- Each seat would have a status (Booked/Available) and a customer ref. (a foreign key).

I am guessing that there will be one 'main' table with a row for every seat, and columns for block, row, position, status, customer etc. With other tables e.g. rows to use as foreign keys.

The problem is I obviously don't want to manually insert every single seat, so how can I do this automatically by inputting how many seats are in a row, then auto-generate seats?

Finally, how can I re-use this, so it could be used more than once for more events? Adding a record for every seat in every event will be resource demanding.

So, what is a way to structure this data, and what would I use to make my life simpler and easily generated?

The program is in java, maybe a function is needed to build the structure?

Comment: I would say structure your solution (model stadium, block, row , seat etc) and then it will become clearer what persistent data you need.

Comment: @c0der Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: I mean model the solution: define classes / object for   stadium, block, row etc. It will make the data you need to store easier to define.

Answer (score 1):

You can create tables like

```
   Table definition                      | Sample data
   Block - Id, Name                      | (1, 'A'), (2, 'B')
    Row - Id, BlockId, Name              | (1 , 1, 'A'), (2 , 1, 'B')
    Seat - Id, rowId, Name               | (1 , 1, 'A1'), (2 , 1, 'A2')

    Event - Id, Name, Date               | (1 , 'Musical Concert', '2016-07/05')

   EventSeats - EventId, SeatId, Status  | (1 , 1, 1), (1 , 2, 0)
```

P.S Status 1 - Booked, Status 0 - Available

If you create models like above you can insert all of the seats of a rows in a block.

Also you can book the seats for each event. The booking information such as the customer name etc can be stored in the EventSeat table. Hope this would answer your final question.

Now let me answer your first question. "I don't want to manually insert every single seat"

It's up to you to implement the logic. 
What you can do is you can get the no of blocks, no of rows in each block and no of seats on each row from the user input.

And loop through it and programmatically insert the data within loop. Hope you got the idea.

Comment: Is there a way to create a record for each of the seats for a new event with SQL? I don't imagine an insert statement for every single seat in a for loop is the most efficient way.

Comment: You want one record for all seats of an event in the event seats ? Then how can you keep track of each of the seats whether they have been booked or not ?

Comment: No sorry, I wish to use your suggestions, but is there a way to automatically insert a new EventSeat record for all of the seats? They need to be there even if they're avaliable.

Comment: I just have given the pseudo code. But you can implement it using Java. Or else alternatively you can implement the same logic using sql stored procedure and call them from Java code

Comment: int newEventId = 2; //e.g
EventSeat eventSeat = null
//Loop through all the blocks
for(Block block in Blocks){

 //Get all rows of each blocks
 for(Row row in block.rows){
 
  //Get all seats of each row
  for(Seat seat in row.seats){
   //Create each entry for one seat
   eventSeat = new EventSeat();
   eventSeat.setSeatId(seat.getSetId());
   eventSeat.setStatus(0);
   .....
   session.save(eventSeat)
  }
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

I am just giving you the pseudo code here, that's given in the comment to give more readability.

Java code

```
int newEventId = 2; //e.g
EventSeat eventSeat = null
//Loop through all the blocks
for(Block block in Blocks){

    //Get all rows of each blocks
    for(Row row in block.rows){

        //Get all seats of each row
        for(Seat seat in row.seats){
            //Create each entry for one seat
            eventSeat = new EventSeat();
            eventSeat.setSeatId(seat.getSetId());
            eventSeat.setStatus(0);
            .....
            session.save(eventSeat)
        }
    }
}
```

Stored prcedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.fillEventSeat @eventId INT
AS

DECLARE @seatCounter INT  @MaxSeatId INT, @seatId INT

SELECT @seatCounter = MIN(Id) , @MaxSeatId = MAX(Id) 
FROM Seat

WHILE(@seatCounter IS NOT NULL
      AND @seatCounter <= @MaxSeatId)

    SELECT @seatId = Id
    FROM Seat WHERE Id = @seatCounter

   INSERT INTO EventSeat(eventId, seatId, status) VALUES (@eventId, @seatId, 0);

   SET @seatCounter  = @seatCounter  + 1        
END
GO
```

Comment: Is a separate insert statement on every EventSeat record efficient? Or is there a better way to add many records?

Comment: Somehow you have to insert all the entries for each seat. If you feel this is bit slow. You may gain bit more advantage, if you use the stored procedure like below.

Comment: You may gain bit more advantage, if you use the stored procedure as shown in the edited answer above.